# How to navigate correctly in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-router, next-link

idk it's pretty simple or what but having difficulty understanding it.
here is one parent div wrapped with nextjs Link tag(which navigates me to /playing route) and in this div i have one more tag which can navigate me to login page.  here is the problem when click on login it navigates first /playing page and then it navigates me to the /login what is the correct way to resolve it.  i want to navigate to the /playing by clicking on whole div and

```
  <Link href="/playing">
        <div className="px-20 w-full">
          <h1 onClick={() => router.push(`/login`)} className="hover:underline">
            Login
          </h1>
        </div>
      </Link>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is caused by `propagation` or `event bubbling`. read `event action` in javascript for more information. But in your section you need to avoid click-through propagation. try this :

```
  <Link href="/playing">
        <div className="px-20 w-full">
          <h1 onClick={(event) => {
           event.stopPropagation();
           router.push(`/login`);
         }} 
         className="hover:underline">
            Login
          </h1>
        </div>
  </Link>
```

if this sample not working. search about event bubbling